# Email is not being sent by SMTP in bitnami redmine

Tags: smtp, actionmailer, redmine, bitnami

Email is not being sent by SMTP in bitnami redmine(4.1.0-8).The following error is coming: 'Email delivery error: SMTP From address may not be blank: nil'.This is my configuration.yml file.

## default configuration options for all environments

default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration
  # See the examples below and the Rails guide for more configuration options:
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:

```
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com'
  port: 587
  domain: 'mycompanydomain.com'
  authentication: :login
  user_name: 'username'
  password: 'password'
```

This configuration.yml file is working perfectly fine in bitnami redmine(4.1.0-0).

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here:

Email settings can be configured in the /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/configuration.yml file. In older versions, use the /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/email.yml file.

The file includes sample configuration settings for most common scenarios, including Gmail. To use Gmail as the SMTP server, find and uncomment the Gmail settings such that you end up with the result below. Remember to update the user_name and password variables with the correct credentials for the Gmail account you plan to use.

```
# ==== SMTP server at using TLS (GMail)
# This might require some additional configuration. See the guides at:
# http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration
#
email_delivery:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    address: "smtp.gmail.com"
    port: 587
    domain: "smtp.gmail.com" # 'your.domain.com' for Google Apps
    authentication: :plain
    user_name: "USERNAME@gmail.com"
    password: "PASSWORD"
```

You can find more information in our documentation https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/redmine/configuration/configure-smtp/

Comment: Yes but it's not working.The following error is coming:'Email delivery error: SMTP From address may not be blank: nil'.It's causing error in redmine version (4.1.0-8) but the exact same configuration.yml file is working fine in redmine version (4.1.0-0).

Comment: Can someone help please?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the application, did you ask the Redmine's developers in its forum?

Comment: You also need to configure the sender address in Redmine in *Administration* -> *Settings* -> *Notifications*. With GMail, this generally must be the same email address you are using in the `configuration.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but it bugs me for an hour to find the answer.

Log into your redmine app and go to settings

br/settings?tab=notifications

The field for the settings[mail_from] MUST be filled

Comment: AND the email must be EXACTLY the same as the email you configure in the config/configuration.yml